# import data from file to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to import file to dictionary for further processing. The file contains embedding vectors for NLP. It looks like:

```
the 0.011384 0.010512 -0.008450 -0.007628 0.000360 -0.010121 0.004674 -0.000076 
of 0.002954 0.004546 0.005513 -0.004026 0.002296 -0.016979 -0.011469 -0.009159 
and 0.004691 -0.012989 -0.003122 0.004786 -0.002907 0.000526 -0.006146 -0.003058
one 0.014722 -0.000810 0.003737 -0.001110 -0.011229 0.001577 -0.007403 -0.005355
```

The code I used is:

```
embeddingTable = {}

with open("D:\\Embedding\\test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val
print(embeddingTable)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3612e9012ffe> in <module>()
 24 with open("D:\\Embedding\\test.txt") as f:
 25     for line in f:
---> 26        (key, val) = line.split()
 27        d[key] = val
 28 print(embeddingTable)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I understand that it expects 2 values not 9, but is there possibility to insert word as key and vectors as value?

Comment: Wouldn't it also make sense to replace `d` with `embeddingTable`?

Comment: Yes of course, just was a draft version. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Masyaf, do you have repeating keys?

Comment: What do you mean? I am relatively new to python :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [`*` operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
embeddingTable = {}
with open("D:\\Embedding\\test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, *values = line.split() # fix here
       embeddingTable[key] = [float(value) for value in values]
print(embeddingTable)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) lib to parse just unpack and [map](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) the vals to floats using a *dict comp*:

```
import csv

with open("D:/Embedding/test.txt") as f:
    d = {k:list(map(float, vals)) for k, *vals in csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use the `*` operator because you're using Python 2, you could do it like below:

```
embeddingTable = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       values = line.split()
       embeddingTable[values[0]] = values[1:]
print(embeddingTable)
```

If you are however using Python 3, please do use the more elegant `*` operator.

Comment: At first I though this answer was pointless since it was posted nearly 10 minutes after a more elegant answer. On the other hand -- the other answer works only in more recent versions of Python 3 but your answer works in Python 2, and OP might need to migrate to Python 2 at some stage because of better support for scientific libraries, so +1.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks. I updated my answer with a note that this would only be a good option if you're stuck with Python 2.

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrase "stuck with". It is a fact of life that there is a huge and growing code base in Python 2, which makes it sometimes the Python of choice -- especially if you intend to use numpy, pandas, etc. (even though by now most of these libraries have Python 3 support, this doesn't help too much in practice since the code which uses these libraries in usually in Python 2)